# What kind of statistical test might be used to if two datasets contain a non-zero lag or lead hierarchically?

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, granger-causality

I am aware of Granger causality, cross correlation, and simple methods of computing correlation at each lag/lead timestep. However, I have a dataset with 1000s of users each with a potential lag/lead effect. How can I infer a lag/lead on each user but some overall lag/lead effect, with an assessment of significance?